# How to properly pass django list/dictionary to javascript

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have a list of items and want to pass it to javascript array.
Django version 2.2.3

**In my views.py:**

```
my_list = ["one", "two"]
    context = {
        'my_list ': json.dumps(my_list),
    }
return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

**my_template.html**

```
<script>
var my_array = JSON.parse("{{ my_list|safe }}")
document.write(my_array )
</script>
```

According to the answers in most topics, my code is valid, but it doesn't display any data. 

**Also tried:**

```
<script>
var my_string = "{{my_list}}";
var my_array = my_string.split(',');
document.write(my_array)
</script>
```

In this case when i want to display it i get

```
[" one  "
```

Comment: you don't have to use `JSON.parse`, here you can get the data by `var my_array = {{ my_list | safe }};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON string literals are enclosed in double quotes, so you should use single quotes around the JSON object instead in JavaScript to avoid conflicts:

```
var my_array = JSON.parse('{{ my_list|safe }}')
```

But then again like @NalinDobhal mentions in the comment, in most cases you can simply assign the JSON object to a JavaScript variable because JSON is designed to follow the syntax of JavaScript.

Comment: Just a note for anyone seeing this answer and using Django version 2.1 or later - this approach is not secure. Use Django's `json_script` template tag instead, as indicated by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865766/3955830) to this question.

Answer (score 1):

[As of Django 2.1, you can now use the json_script template tag to include a python object as JSON in your template.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

In your case, that would look like this:

```
{{ my_list |json_script:"my_array" }}
```

You can then access it from your script with:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('my_array').textContent);
```